# How to kill a process running in a port in a remote aws server

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, client-server

I am trying to kill a process running in

```
http://54.218.73.244:7002/
```

i have used the command

```
fuser -k 7002/tcp
```

it is not working the process continues to run

I am using expressJS in server to run the server script

how can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ssh 54.218.73.244 fuser -k 7002/tcp
```